# SQL Server column dependencies check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server database with a table that requires an alter to change the length of a char column from length 10 to 20.

And that table is used in many procedures, views, UDF's and triggers etc.

1. I need to know if there's a query to check those dependencies
2. If I alter the table, how can I make sure its dependencies are also updated?
3. Is there a way to make that alter on all those dependencies using query?

Answer (score 0):

There is no really quick way to do this with a query.  However I've had the same problem in the past and you can script out the database schema and search for references, like this:

- in Microsoft SQL Studio, right click on the database
- click on `Tasks`
- click on `Generate Scripts`
- next
- choose `Script entire database and all database objects`
- script to a file (next)
- next
- next

You will now have a text file that can be used to make your entire structure.  So... open it up in `notepad` or your favorite text editor.  Now just do a `find` and look for references to your column by name.  This can be a little tedious but it's the only way I know of really checking your whole database to see if any `UDF`, `stored procedure`, etc. referencing that column.

What this will *not* help with if there is any application layer or code outside of your database that references it.  It will also not help if there is a linked server or other databases that reference this column.  Hope this helps!